# Image processing/restoration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have several images that i would like to correct from artifacts. They show different animals but they appear to look like they were folded (look at the image attached). The folds are straight and they go through the wings as well, they are just hard to see but they are there. I would like to remove the folds but at the same time preserve the information from the picture (structure and color of the wings).
I am using MATLAB right now and i have tried several methods but nothing seems to work.

Initially i tried to see if i can see anything by using an FFT but i do not see a structure in the spectrum that i can remove. I tried to use several edge detection methods (like Sobel, etc) but the problem is that the edge detection always finds the edges of the wings (because they are stronger)
rather than the straight lines. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to proceed with this problem? I am not attaching any code because none of the methods i have tried (and described) are working.

Thank you for the help in advance.

[image: Example]

Comment: Interesting! I wonder what causes these artifacts? If you could model it then you might be able to formulate a solution.

Comment: i am not sure what caused it. They seem straight though but that has not helped.

Comment: several sounds like a job for Photoshop to me...

Comment: Take the horizontal derivative of the image, then apply the line-finding transform (hough i think). There should be a discontinuity in the derivative around the fold that the transform can catch.Seeing what happens to the derivative should help you build a model to eliminate the problem.

Comment: By horizontal derivative I just mean `diff`

Comment: Are they always at the same locations in all images?

Comment: from what i can tell, they have the same distance between them but they are not in the same pixel location in every image.

Comment: do you have the raw data (i.e. before jpeg compression)?

Comment: maybe you should look into wavelet anaysis as opposed to fft2, I imagine you could filter out the sharp image transitions more easily

Comment: in fact i was just trying that. I did the wavelet first and then try to see if i can see the lines as bright spots in the FFT but unfortunately i could not find them.

Comment: @Mercury, no unfortunately i do not have the raw data.

Comment: I would like to hear more about this. Where do the images come from? They must have been processed to cause these artifacts, or is this because of a faulty camera? If they are not always at the same locations, were the images cropped? (i.e. they used to be at the same locations before cropping?) -- Understanding the source of the artifacts is the first step in removing them. :)

Comment: I am not sure where the artifacts come from. All i can say is that the distance between them seem to be the same in all images, but they are not in the same pixel location. My guess is whatever happened must have been when the image was taken or maybe scanned.

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave this bit here for anyone that knows how to erase those lines without affecting the quality of the image:

```
a = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpFAA.jpg');
b = abs(diff(a,1,2));
b = max(b,[],3);
c = imerode(b,strel('rectangle',[200,1]));
```

[image]

Comment: The term is image in painting, it will probably work just with averaging the surrounding pixels. However I suspect that the problem is more than just the lines, its a smooth degradation of the brightness of the image up to the line, and then an abrupt change

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Indeed. This is why it would be nice to know where the artifacts came from.

Comment: I agree, i think if it was just the lines (by the way there are some on the left side too  but i can play around with the size of the strel and see if i can see all of them) they might look darker, so i am also guessing that they dip in intensity in a neighborhood around the center of the lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a 2-dimensional Fast Fourier Transform 
It might be easier to first use GIMP / Photoshop if a filter can resolve it.

I'm guessing the CC sensor got broken (it looks to good for old scanner problems). Maybe an electric distortion while it was reading the camera sensor. Such signals in theory have a repeating nature.
I dont think this was caused by a wrong colordepth/colorspace translation

If you like to code, then you might also write a custom pixel based filter in which you take x vertical pixels (say 20 or so) compare them to the next vertical row of 20 pixels. Compare against HSL (L lightnes), not RGB.
From all pixels calculate brightness changes this way.
Then per pixel check H (heu) is within range of nearby pixels take slope average of their brightness(ea take 30 pixels horizontal, calculate average brightnes of first 10 and last 10 pixels apply that brightness to center pixel 15,... //30, 15, 10 try to find what works well

Since you have whole strokes that apear brighter/darker such filter would smooth that effect out, the difficulty is to remain other patterns (the wings are less distorted), knowing what color space the sensor had might  allow for a better decision as HSL, maybe HSV or so..

Comment: Lightness is either defined as a linear combination of R, G and B, or as the maximum of the three. Why do you think using either of those is going to give better results? I found that the green channel had the most visible jump, so averaging the channels together, or using the brightest channel, is likely going to diminish the contrast of the jump. -- "knowing what color space the sensor had": I have seen a few imaging systems (cameras and scanners) that do not use RGB sensors, but none of those produce normal color images.

Comment: light can have many definitions, RGB doesnt code that easily for differences, ea light can have a color (H) heu, but different lightness, or difefrent saturation, HSL and HSV are more close to color perception despite that monitors work with RGB. If one knows the CCD that caused it, and what channels it had, you might use that color seperation as well (and maybe still do hsl then).. 

(small fun fact purple does not exist, our brains make it up nature doesnt contain it).

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that the CCD that took this image (if it was a CCD) had RGB pixels. There are no imaging systems that work with HSV or HSL or CIEYxy or CIELab or anything else. They all divide up the spectrum in some way to image individual channels. Our eyes also have receptors that are sensitive to different wavelengths of light. This is why monitors work with RGB too. They stimulate the right receptors to create the right color stimulus. (Continued...)

Comment: (Continued) Color perception happens very early on in our vision system, in the first layer behind the receptors, but our eyes still first sense light of different wavelengths. Out color perception is not related to hue values at all. Hue is the angle in the chromaciry plane. Our eyes send signals to our brain more closely related to the tristimulus values (CIEYxy or CIELab). But all of that is a moot point: the image's origin is in RGB, so the artifacts appear in the RGB channels. IMO, this is not about perception at all.

Comment: the attractive point of HSL is the way it can handle Lightness while staying the same color, its why artist (in history) made color tables like it. In the sample its only L that goes wrong but color stays the same. Thats why i recomended it. Its a better aprouch as compared to your code, but if you like you can have the points i dont care

Comment: This is not at all about points, it's about having interesting discussions and learning new things.

Comment: OK use less aggresive writing style, you got me in deffense.
I code almost weekly in graphics for 5 years now and often use HSL, besides other models, its ideal for some advanced noise /intensity /contrast filter algorithms. But something thats written in Chinese can be translated to English as well, its about preference as well.
I wonder what has caused the banding chromasub samplng gone wrong ? Old scanner electronics, or a non standard aged CCD chip